# Is it just me or is powershell having trouble reading range of numbers 6-9 (out of 1-52)?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm running into some issues where the user input should be validated if numbers 1-52 are inputted. However numbers 6-9 are the only numbers it is giving an error for some reason...

Here is the code:

```
Function PrintArrayAsGridWithDisplayNumber
{
    param([string[]]$Array,[ValidateRange(1,24)][int]$ColumnCount)

    [int]$arrDisplayNumCounter = 1
    $GridSplat = @{
        InputObject = $Array|ForEach-Object {
            New-Object psobject -Property @{'Value' = "$arrDisplayNumCounter - " + $_};
            $arrDisplayNumCounter++
        }
        Property    = 'Value'
    }

    if(-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ColumnCount'))
    {
        $GridSplat['AutoSize'] = $true
    }
    else
    {
        $GridSplat['Column'] = $ColumnCount
    }

    $table = Format-Wide @GridSplat | Out-String
    Write-Host $table
}

Function AskUserSelectUserPropertiesToQueryAD
{
Param ()
[String[]]$validAdProperties = @('SamAccountName', 'msRTCSIP-UserEnabled', 'msRTCSIP-OptionFlags', 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress', 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryHomeServer', 
'mail', 'msExchMasterAccountSid', 'homeMDB', 'proxyaddresses', 'legacyExchangeDN', 
'lastLogonTimestamp', 'logonCount', 'lastLogoff', 'lastLogon', 'pwdLastSet', 'userAccountControl', 'whenCreated', 'whenChanged', 'accountExpires', 
'sn', 'givenName', 'displayName', 'distinguishedName', 'initials', 'l', 'st', 'street', 'title', 'description', 'postalCode', 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName', 
'telephoneNumber', 'facsimileTelephoneNumber', 'info', 'memberOf', 'co', 'department', 'company', 'streetAddress', 'employeeNumber', 'employeeType', 'objectGUID', 
'employeeID', 'homeDirectory', 'homeDrive', 'scriptPath', 'objectSid', 'userPrincipalName', 'url', 'msDS-SourceObjectDN', 'manager', 'extensionattribute8')
[Int]$displayDemoNumber = 40
[Int]$numOfDisplayColumns = 3
[String]$displayDemoNumberValue = $validAdProperties[$displayDemoNumber - 1]

PrintArrayAsGridWithDisplayNumber $validAdProperties $numOfDisplayColumns

$selectedAdPropertiesQuery = @()
$minValidNumber = 1
$maxValidNumber = $validAdProperties.length
While (($userInput -notlike "f*"))
{
    # Ask user input
    If (!($selectedAdPropertiesQuery))
    {
        $userInput = Read-Host "    Enter number to select property to export in search results csv file (e.g.: for $displayDemoNumberValue, enter $displayDemoNumber )"
    } Else {
        $userInput = Read-Host "    Enter number to select property to add in search results csv file, or enter `"f`" if finished"
    }

    # Write error if user input was not valid number or f. Else add search value to array if number is valid and not like f.
    If ((($userInput -lt $minValidNumber) -or ($userInput -gt $maxValidNumber)) -and ($userInput -notlike "f*")) # write warning and do not include input as a value
    {
        Write-Host '$minValidNumber =' $minValidNumber
        Write-Host '$maxValidNumber =' $maxValidNumber
        Write-Host '$userInput =' $userInput
        Write-Warning "Invalid number entered: $userInput `nnumber was out of range($minValidNumber - $maxValidNumber)"
        Write-Host ""
    } ElseIf ((($userInput -ge $minValidNumber) -or ($userInput -le $maxValidNumber)) -and ($userInput -notlike "f*")) {
        $userValidatedInput = $validAdProperties[$userInput - 1] # selected property
        $selectedAdPropertiesQuery += $userValidatedInput
        Write-Host "User Properties Selected = $selectedAdPropertiesQuery"
        Write-Host ""
    }
}

Write-Output $selectedAdPropertiesQuery
}

AskUserSelectUserPropertiesToQueryAD
```

[image]

Note: If I cast the `Read-Host` to `[Int]Read-Host`, the numbers will be successful, but will error out when you enter `f` causing an infinite loop. I tried several things, but I just can't seem to get it quite right.

If anyone could help me understand, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `Read-Host`, the input becomes a `string`, when you then try to compare `$userInput` to numbers, it uses the ASCII value for `$userInput` when the string is a single char.

Example:

```
# If I input 6 here...
$userInput = Read-Host "    Enter number to select property to add in search results csv file, or enter 'f' if finished"

# ...this will show 54
[byte][char]$userInput 

# if Max is set to 52, this will be true, since 54 is naturally larger than 52
$userInput -gt $maxValidNumber
```

To fix this, you can try to coerce `$userInput` to an int in your check with `[int]`, like this:

```
(([int]$userInput -lt $minValidNumber) -or ([int]$userInput -gt $maxValidNumber)) -and ($userInput -notlike "f*")
```

Comment: Problem is entering `f` still prints an error, because it still tries to convert it to int. I finally found the answer after working on this for 4 hours. It basically boils down to using multiple casts (because even after going through the loop, the previous cast remains stuck with the variable name when being re-assigned). I'll post the answer below.

Comment: Although, I do thank you for showing me the reason it is not reading it as an Int. The default type for assigning a variable is [byte][char] unless casted to a specific type. This will be good to know in the future, and technically it does answer the question of why it's not reading it.

Answer (score 1):

After 4 hours of trial and error (3 prior to posting this question) I finally found the answer.

```
Function PrintArrayAsGridWithDisplayNumber
{
    param([string[]]$Array,[ValidateRange(1,24)][int]$ColumnCount)

    [int]$arrDisplayNumCounter = 1
    $GridSplat = @{
        InputObject = $Array|ForEach-Object {
            New-Object psobject -Property @{'Value' = "$arrDisplayNumCounter - " + $_};
            $arrDisplayNumCounter++
        }
        Property    = 'Value'
    }

    if(-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ColumnCount'))
    {
        $GridSplat['AutoSize'] = $true
    }
    else
    {
        $GridSplat['Column'] = $ColumnCount
    }

    $table = Format-Wide @GridSplat | Out-String
    Write-Host $table
}

Function AskUserSelectUserPropertiesToQueryAD
{
    [String[]]$validAdProperties = @('SamAccountName', 'msRTCSIP-UserEnabled', 'msRTCSIP-OptionFlags', 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress', 'msRTCSIP-PrimaryHomeServer', 
    'mail', 'msExchMasterAccountSid', 'homeMDB', 'proxyaddresses', 'legacyExchangeDN', 
    'lastLogonTimestamp', 'logonCount', 'lastLogoff', 'lastLogon', 'pwdLastSet', 'userAccountControl', 'whenCreated', 'whenChanged', 'accountExpires', 
    'sn', 'givenName', 'displayName', 'distinguishedName', 'initials', 'l', 'st', 'street', 'title', 'description', 'postalCode', 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName', 
    'telephoneNumber', 'facsimileTelephoneNumber', 'info', 'memberOf', 'co', 'department', 'company', 'streetAddress', 'employeeNumber', 'employeeType', 'objectGUID', 
    'employeeID', 'homeDirectory', 'homeDrive', 'scriptPath', 'objectSid', 'userPrincipalName', 'url', 'msDS-SourceObjectDN', 'manager', 'extensionattribute8')
    [Int]$displayDemoNumber = 40
    [Int]$numOfDisplayColumns = 3
    [String]$displayDemoNumberValue = $validAdProperties[$displayDemoNumber - 1]

    PrintArrayAsGridWithDisplayNumber $validAdProperties $numOfDisplayColumns

    $selectedAdPropertiesQuery = @()
    $minValidNumber = 1
    $maxValidNumber = $validAdProperties.length
    While (($userInput -notlike "f*"))
    {
        [Bool]$invalidInput = $false
        # Ask user input
        If (!($selectedAdPropertiesQuery))
        {
            [String]$userInput = (Read-Host "   Enter number to select property to export in search results csv file (e.g.: for $displayDemoNumberValue, enter $displayDemoNumber )").Trim()
        } Else {
            [String]$userInput = (Read-Host "   Enter number to select property to add in search results csv file, or enter `"f`" if finished").Trim()
        }


        Write-Host '$userInput =' $userInput
        If ($userInput -notlike "f*")
        {
            Try {
                [Int]$userInput = $userInput
            } Catch {
                Write-Warning "Your input is not a number or `"f`""
                [Bool]$invalidInput = $true
            }
        }

        # Write error if user input was not valid number or f. Else add search value to array if number is valid and not like f.
        If ((($userInput -lt $minValidNumber) -or ($userInput -gt $maxValidNumber)) -and ($userInput -notlike "f*") -and (!($invalidInput))) # write warning and do not include input as a value
        {
            Write-Host '$minValidNumber =' $minValidNumber
            Write-Host '$maxValidNumber =' $maxValidNumber
            Write-Host '$userInput =' $userInput
            Write-Warning "Invalid number entered: $userInput `nnumber was out of range($minValidNumber - $maxValidNumber)"
            Write-Host ""
        } ElseIf ((($userInput -ge $minValidNumber) -or ($userInput -le $maxValidNumber)) -and ($userInput -notlike "f*") -and (!($invalidInput))) {
            $userValidatedInput = $validAdProperties[$userInput - 1] # selected property
            $selectedAdPropertiesQuery += $userValidatedInput
            Write-Host "User Properties Selected = $selectedAdPropertiesQuery"
            Write-Host ""
        }
    }
    Write-Output $selectedAdPropertiesQuery
}

AskUserSelectUserPropertiesToQueryAD
```

Details are in my comment in responding to Negorath's answer...

Comment: _Details are in my comment in responding to Negorath's answer..._. No. They should be here in your answer so that people don't have to go searching for them. What happens when those comments get deleted?